# Google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, recaptcha

Как сделать обьязательным поле google recaptcha?
Например если пользователь не прошел капчу то кнопка отправить не работает

Comment: код можно?...хотя бы не рабочий

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');

    if($recaptcha) {
        $recaptcha.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }
  const $form = document.querySelector('form');
  $form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented submit by code for demo');
  });
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 100px;
}

#g-recaptcha-response {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -78px 0 0 0 !important;
    width: 302px !important;
    height: 76px !important;
    z-index: -999999;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form>
     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcCsWoUAAAAAO520lKAXtblM0p76KNXL3n0dVUZ"></div>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Чтобы посмотреть на пример в работе: https://codepen.io/internetztube/pen/aaoLqM

Суть кода заключается в том, чтобы после загрузки страницы повесить на `input g-recaptcha-response` атрибут `required`. Так как базовых возможностей нет. Всегда пользовался этим решением, никогда не подводил.

**UPD:**

```
$form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented submit by code for demo');
  });
```

Вот тут перехватывается отправка. Вместо `console.log('prevented submit by code for demo');` иницируете отправку формы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но после прохождения капчи кнопка не работает, (form action="mail.php")

Comment: @user322352 дополнил ответ.

Comment: Все также кнопка не риагирует

Comment: $form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('mail.php');
  });  
Я правильно сделал или как? Я пока что новичок, прошу строго не судить

Comment: @user322352 вместо той строки что я привёл `document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); `  где myform ID вашей формы.

Comment: Вот что получилось

<form action="mail.php" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваша почта">
     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcCsWoUAAAAAO520lKAXtblM0p76KNXL3n0dVUZ"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

Comment: <script>
 window.onload = function() {
    var $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');

    if($recaptcha) {
        $recaptcha.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }
  const $form = document.querySelector('form');
  $form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  });
};
</script>